# Clickable map overlay in OL3?

Tags: javascript, css, overlay, openlayers-3

I have a map overlay which displays the image of a house through its element parameter when the user navigates to the property they have searched for.

The problem is I have a search tool which allows the user to search the map based on a map click; when the user finds their property they click on the house image but it does not activate the search because the image blocks the map click option.

Is there a way I can allow the user to click on the map through the image? Would this be done with CSS or are there parameters / properties for the overlay element that I can set which will allow this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On re-reading the Openlayers examples, there is an option to stop event propagation so I set this to false and it allowed me to query the map through the overlay marker image.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to your DOM (overlay) element:

```
overlay_element.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // call your search function
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas - I did find this but the map click will fire one of a number of different functions depending on what is activated.

In this instance I may need to include several if statements to identify what functions are active - are there any other ways to ignore the overlay element itself when activating the map click?